# Replace specific words with markdown links in a text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, string, next.js

I've got a text saved in a longer string and want to replace some words of the text with a highlighted version or a markdown link to a glossary page where the words are described. The words that should be filtered are stored in a string array.

At the moment my code looks something like this:

```js
const text = "Lorem ipsum xxx dolor sit amet."
const highlightedWords = ["xxx", "yyy"]

const newText = text.replace(new RegExp(highlightedWords.join("|"), "gi"), "[same-word-here]('/glossary#same-word-here)');
```

The part with **same-word-here** should be the same word that was replaced before, but I don't know how to get this one in this position.

If you need a better known example: It should look like a linked article in a wikipedia text

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the the expression in a capture group `()`, and then use `$1` to use the capture group's content. You should also use `\b` (word boundary) to prevent text replacement when it's in another work, for example "xxxzzz".

```js
const text = "Lorem ipsum xxx dolor sit amet."
const highlightedWords = ["xxx", "yyy"]

const newText = text.replace(new RegExp(`\\b(${highlightedWords.join("|")})\\b`, "gi"), "[$1]('/glossary#same-word-here)'");

console.log(newText)
```

Comment: If the "words" to be highlighted have any chance of containing regex special characters (like parentheses or square brackets), [they can be escaped before joining them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1426891).

Comment: Thank you! This seems to works for me. Never really heard of this feature before.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you don't need regex for this since you have an array of words to iterate through.

```js
let text = 'Lorem ipsum xxx dolor sit yyy amet.';
const highlightedWords = ['xxx', 'yyy'];

for (word of highlightedWords) {
    if (text.includes(word))
        text = text.replace(word, `[${word}]('/glossary#${word})`);
}

console.log(newText);
// result: Lorem ipsum [xxx]('/glossary#xxx) dolor sit [yyy]('/glossary#yyy) amet.
```

Or use a new variable so you still have original if you need it

```js
const text = 'Lorem ipsum xxx dolor sit yyy amet.';
const highlightedWords = ['xxx', 'yyy'];

let newText = text;
for (word of highlightedWords) {
    if (newText.includes(word))
        newText = newText.replace(word, `[${word}]('/glossary#${word})`);
}

console.log(newText);
// result: Lorem ipsum [xxx]('/glossary#xxx) dolor sit [yyy]('/glossary#yyy) amet.
```

Comment: Thank you too! Both ways solved my problem.
I mean in my case performance is not a thing because my function runs in next SSG, but would the for loop be more performant than a regular expression? Just asking for personal interest.

Comment: @nolliebigspin I have no idea. I learned about using join to make a regexp from an array thanks to your post and Ori Drori answer. I like it because it's a one liner. I just didn't understand it at first. Maybe someone more knowledgeable will comment on performance eventually.